# Why i can't push files in array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, filesystems

I have a function for recursively finding files.
if type D is specified, I want only folders to be added to the array. and if type F then only files. It works fine with file search. but if type D then nothing can be added although it is possible to output to the console.
Why can't I add to the array and how can I fix it

```
const type = T or D

const walk = (dir, done) => {
    let results = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(dir, (err, list) => {
            if (err) return done(err);
            let pending = list.length;
            if (!pending) return done(null, results);
            list.forEach((file) => {
                file = path.join(dir, file);
                fs.stat(file, function (err, stat) {
                    if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                        if (type && type === 'D') {
                            console.log(file)
                            results.push(file);
                        }
                        walk(file, (err, res) => {
                            results.push(...res);
                            if (!--pending) done(null, results);
                        });
                    } else {
                        if (type === 'F') {
                            results.push(file);
                            if (!--pending) done(null, results);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    })
};

walk(baseDir, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: This is a weird implementation.  You're returning a promise (that you never resolve) AND taking a `done()` callback.  You also are missing error handling in several places.

Answer (score 0):

When `type` is `D`, you're currently decrementing `pending` only inside the `if (stat && stat.isDirectory())` block, but `pending`'s amount also depends on the number of *files* in the directory, due to `let pending = list.length;`.

One way to fix it would be to decrement `pending` inside the `else` regardless:

```
} else {
    if (type === 'F') {
        results.push(file);
    }
    if (!--pending) done(null, results);
}
```

Or, to be cleaner and avoid some of the callback hell, use `async` functions and `await` instead, and then you can use `Promise.all` instead of manually checking indicies (which is tedious and can be error-prone). This also makes the function return a Promise properly (when `done` isn't passed):

```
const walk = async (dir, done) => {
    try {
        const list = await readdir(dir);
        const resultsArr = await Promise.all(list.map(async (fileName) => {
            const filePath = path.join(dir, fileName);
            const stats = await stat(filePath);
            if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                if (type === 'D') {
                    return [filePath, ...await walk(filePath)];
                }
                return walk(filePath);
            } else if (!stats.isDirectory() && type === 'F') {
                return filePath;
            }
        }));
        const flatResults = resultsArr.flat().filter(Boolean);
        if (done) {
            done(null, flatResults);
        }
        return flatResults;
    } catch (err) {
        if (done) {
            done(err);
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    }
};
```